# Convert Vega (Deneb) Gauge to Work in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, vega-lite, vega, deneb

Code: [Link](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAB3GgBN6aAMwAGNTPg0yWVRpk4kChTXFk0AzSCZIoAazIAnNg3EK0IAMQAmPwBYVAEZpEAgdcSQAGwg0AG1QSIQ4T0w4AA9MAHEnYxo4cUxQhhwFJDTPYGc8gsxUAAIAciizOCQnRql6iEw2PAaEtgAzIYg4OvrNeqg2KLYnBsavIP8FAA4oKEaAXy7gYdHxhqCumbmFpq9-KDWmODgdgF1tkF3EpGTPHDgnKFri0rlFLoNYqV6PGRlTAoVAJEBJYE2Oz2ULEaIMOCxWEQkCYXLiCBDeYIeKgTAAT2+njGAEcMeI-qEeu0iqhrD0+mgggYwmkcFyZEgsSA0VFXlIyZTEUSnAgGFEUDIMjgnJ4QoLhUU3ripV98qEhvkoh50EUZMynJgAILmKLA0DhMiRMXoNTikAFBQ2sh2tAOiLRTw+ABUAAUAJKvbbPCXwj7SlyFVHozHxHF4pAEmUk2GSqnoWn0xnm6GWtDs3r81D+p2B9DfX7-Xa8uBVk4gIWeUXivPS4nyxUe9IqtWhTumns6-MgHD6mSGuDG1JM0vW232sIBl0gN3Nz3e33Vze17cAClPIYjAEoCNy1Ffgw2-knttHo+aoNFU7m4590Gd5lCClpxacQ2lVSE2GQMw-RAKEYSRBwDSNE0RUDZt8TIYE4m8FZ1k2UIrhuO4UhkLwADYBHIgB2e5CKYAQVBUBQfHoxjmNY54cWQJx7CxOFgMRdooANFwc1AeDPFsJC9wZNgFA3Woflgw0ohdUBRQxTwvBUIZ-B8fwUmbdJYMdZ1PHkJQYHqAh6lY5tyVMrdPG0XRMBsuyoxkEooQ3C01x9DcFyXAtVwPIylXccKVJQzx93Xd0jC9BKjzMusd0oNQggEd0zDApwACU8gYLEa3M9BT0s+gPJ8K8AFpsvdVw0kK4rSuPcq5EUarbPs19tUEzxhNEqDYMk9AhkTLVIpmBTYKU1Uj1U9Swk-Q8QAAiCQGC1Du2MpyTws7rrN691HNS5z0FcrAaq8kAfKBUywpS0AdupZ7AvdeLPqW2L0G+31myS6KLsO11Msa5s8p+IrTBKg7Osq46avqyGZGamG2oR9KqpOzz+oG3V0GGyFyhhOEYSCd8PTkuajwWmK1NgzTER0vSDIikATNBzrcduhzse3a73NO19vMBCpUo+w8yvS3dIuSn7Ze3S9Iyh8R8thmh4Z59KkaslG6p8HLmwx1q4fatKzz53r6p8Xd+tjQbTQyM04LJ0lqYKWaNweyWyVdwWvh+Z93IAaiaABSRp3WiCJmZTTxQ+U5siUKAB1OAdD0I8Wak2YPFTmgmd17c0kyHIahfGRueVo6DYIeyZHOuv0Btpu4JbtCoi01BuVTiRMAAZRoAAvDc89Qai1AJp2idxQPSehT2cW9+TfYljdy9ZDTE-QCR6lLLDpo7FonQTnvEWT1UB4zrO3Iv3ubAL91lsf1mAE41A-nwkBCfbS71x6h3LuVsgEnQ7goLuk9-Az3nIPEe49376AJs8IAA)

For me it seems like the value of "83%" is hardcoded and I want this to adjust based on a Power BI Measure. I feel like I am really missing something, but isn't there a way to import the JSON, adjust the code and then have a dynamic visual ?

In this screenshot I try to explain what I mean:
[deneb visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox5Mv.png)

I tried to remove the "signals" part and bind the data to the dataset, but I couldn't make it work.

Thanks for any hint :)

Update:
Screenshot os unformatted value added:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's my code . You can see other examples here: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase

To get this to work in Deneb, create a measure named myMeasure and drop it in the field well in Deneb. Then add the following code.

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 400,
  "padding": 50,
  "background": "#222431",
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "textGradient",
      "update": "{gradient: 'linear', stops: [{offset: 0, color: '#14d8cc'}, {offset: 1, color: '#4c8bee'}]}"
    },
    {
      "name": "percent",
      "update": "0",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {
            "type": "timer",
            "throttle": 0
          },
          "update": "round(data('dataset')[0]['myMeasure'])"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {"name": "dataset"},
    {
      "name": "back",
      "values": [],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "sequence",
          "start": 0,
          "stop": 100,
          "step": 1,
          "as": "val"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "1",
          "as": "t"
        },
        {
          "type": "pie",
          "field": "t",
          "startAngle": {"signal": "0"},
          "endAngle": {"signal": "2*PI"}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "front",
      "values": [],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "sequence",
          "start": 0,
          "stop": {"signal": "percent"},
          "step": 1,
          "as": "val"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "1",
          "as": "t"
        },
        {
          "type": "pie",
          "field": "t",
          "startAngle": {"signal": "0"},
          "endAngle": {
            "signal": "((2*PI)/100)*percent"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {
        "data": "back",
        "field": "val"
      },
      "range": [
        "#14d8cc",
        "#4c8bee",
        "#6567ee",
        "#b533d2",
        "#b533d2"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "arc",
      "from": {"data": "back"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"value": "#3f424e"},
          "x": {"signal": "width / 2"},
          "y": {"signal": "height / 2"}
        },
        "update": {
          "startAngle": {
            "field": "startAngle"
          },
          "endAngle": {
            "field": "endAngle"
          },
          "padAngle": {
            "signal": "0.015"
          },
          "innerRadius": {
            "signal": "(width / 2)-15"
          },
          "outerRadius": {
            "signal": "width / 2"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "arc",
      "from": {"data": "front"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {
            "scale": "color",
            "field": "val"
          },
          "x": {"signal": "width / 2"},
          "y": {"signal": "height / 2"}
        },
        "update": {
          "startAngle": {
            "field": "startAngle"
          },
          "endAngle": {
            "field": "endAngle"
          },
          "padAngle": {
            "signal": "0.015"
          },
          "innerRadius": {
            "signal": "(width / 2)-15"
          },
          "outerRadius": {
            "signal": "width / 2"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "arc",
      "data": [{"a": 1}],
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"value": "#3f424e"},
          "x": {"signal": "width / 2"},
          "y": {"signal": "height / 2"}
        },
        "update": {
          "startAngle": {"signal": "0"},
          "endAngle": {
            "signal": "2*PI"
          },
          "innerRadius": {
            "signal": "(width / 2)-25"
          },
          "outerRadius": {
            "signal": "(width / 2)-20"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "data": [{}],
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "text": {
            "signal": "percent + '%'"
          },
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "fontWeight": {
            "value": "bold"
          },
          "fill": {
            "signal": "textGradient"
          },
          "x": {"signal": "width /2"},
          "y": {"signal": "width /2"},
          "dy": {"value": 10},
          "fontSize": {"value": 70}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "data": [{}],
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "text": {
            "value": "on target"
          },
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "fontWeight": {
            "value": "bold"
          },
          "fill": {"value": "#9092a1"},
          "x": {"signal": "width /2"},
          "y": {"signal": "width /2"},
          "dy": {"value": 40},
          "fontSize": {"value": 30}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation David! This really helps a lot. 

Anyway the value is not formatted correctly, as you can see in my screenshot. Where exactly do I have to place the format string ? I found this [tutorial](https://deneb-viz.github.io/formatting)

Comment: This gauge goes from 0 to 100 so you need to supply as a percentage in those bounds or change the code to allow different scales.

Comment: It seems like the value is just not displayed correctly. I have added a screenshot in the first comment. 
It looks like the deneb visual ignores the "." as a separator...

Comment: I'll update the code now. Please mark as solved.

Comment: Thanks David, works as expected! :)